# Mysql inserts zero in field of db with default value 9999999

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with statement in mysql.
I have a field in mysql table called *Code* which is defined as Interger(7) NOT NULL Default 9999999.

My problem is when I do this statement sql:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (Id, Code) VALUES ('123','');
```

I get to insert in field *Code* value zero (0).
Why not insert value 9999999 in field *Code*?

Thanks.

Comment: interger is not a word and (7) is (almost) meaningless

Comment: If the `Id` column's values are also integers, you don't need to encapsulate the value in quote marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value is used only when no value is provided. try to insert without provide the Code column value

```
INSERT INTO mytable (Id, Code) VALUES ('123');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to insert `null` instead of an empty string (or provide no value at all like @Vipin mentioned).

```
INSERT INTO mytable (Id, Code) 
VALUES ('123', NULL);
```

An empty string is still a value and the default is only used when NO value is provided.

Since `code` is an `int` field, MySQL tries to convert the `''` to a number and the result is `0`.

Comment: I have inserted NULL and the result is the same, it insert a value ZERO. Anyway, why insert value ZERO with empty string or NULL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
INSERT INTO mytable (Id) VALUES ('123');
```

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it.
>   Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.

that's why you can not insert default value in case of `null`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: In first case I get default value 9999999, in second case I get value ZERO.

Comment: you want default value ?

Comment: I want default value when it was NULL o empty. I don´t know if user will insert a value in the form or not.

Answer (score 0):

Example of default value in a specific field has given below

```
GO
ALTER TABLE Table_name  ADD
    column_name decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT Constant_name DEFAULT 0
GO
ALTER TABLE Table_name SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
COMMIT
```